# How to process numerous files from two folders in a loop using R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am working on Lidar(Light Detection and Ranging) data to produce an output called CHM (canopy height Model). I need two types of file with the same extension which is stored in two different folders. Basically, these two files don't have same characteristics so I am trying to apply different function for the files stored in two folders. For example, here is the code that I want to run

## Setting the directory for one type of files

`setwd("D:\\Raw_RS_Data\\LiDAR_Ground")`

`getwd()`

`fileList <- list.files(path "D:\\Raw_RS_Data\\LiDAR_Ground", pattern = ".las")`
 fileList

```
for (i in 1:length(fileList)) # apply loop function for all the files in this folder
```

{

`MyLas <- readLAS(fileList[i])` #read all the las files in the directory
      `MyDTM <- grid_terrain(MyLas, res = 0.5, method = "knnidw", k = 6)` # create DTM from the las files
  # Need to change the directory for different files stored in the folder "D:\Raw_RS_Data\LiDAR_Non_Ground" and execute the function lasnormalize in the same loop

`MyNorm <- lasnormalize(MyLas, MyDTM)` # Normalize the lasfiles

## The final output I need is CHM and here is the function for CHM

`MyCHM = grid_canopy(MyNorm, res = 0.5, start = c(0, 0))`

}

Alternatively, if I can combine those files stored in the different folder, then I could apply the function with only one loop. So, also don't know how to combine the files from different folder into one.

Thanks and Regards,
Yogendra

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, do you need the files in the two separate folders to be processed within iterations or is it out of convenience that you wish to process them in the same loop?

Comment: I want to process them (files stored in two folders) in the same loop but using different function.

Comment: could you also please format the code in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Would the following work? The question is a bit ambiguous but here's my shot at the interpretation:

```
#note that in general using "/" is better than "\"
file_path.1 = "D:/folder/non_ground"
file_path.2 = "D:/folder/ground"

#get the files of interest with full path name
files_non_ground = paste(file_path.1,dir(file_path.1, ".las"), sep='/')
files_ground = paste(file_path.1,dir(file_path.2, ".las"), sep='/')

#concatenate them into a single vector
files = c(files_non_ground, files_ground)

#initiate some storage container
out.list = list()

#iterate over files:
for(f in files){
  MyLas <- readLAS(f)
  MyDTM <- grid_terrain(MyLas, res = 0.5, method = "knnidw", k = 6)
  MyNorm <- lasnormalize(MyLas, MyDTM)
  writeLAS(MyNorm,sub(".las", "norm.las", f))
  #out.list[f] = MyNorm
}
```

Just please be advised that I am not sure what's happening inside the `for` loop, the above is just my guess. Also, I think it is generally preferable to use full file path names instead of setting directories, especially when dealing with multiple folders.

Comment: Hi, I have tried the code you suggested, it is working. But how could I save the MyNorm file using the same or part of the characters of the filename from the file list stored in one of my folders? Also, can I create a new output file in the same loop which will be stored in the given path? Here is my code that I want to save the output file in a loop after creating the MyNorm file.

`output <- paste0(substr(files[i], start = 1, stop = 11), "norm.las")`
 
`dir.create(paste0("NORM"), showWarnings = FALSE)`
 
`NormLas <- writeLAS (MyNorm, file.path(paste0("NORM"), output))`

Comment: so basically, you wish to save the MyNorm file with the `"norm.las"` replacing the `".las"` part of the file? `f` contains the entire file path so all you have to do is `writeLAS(MyNorm,sub(".las", "norm.las", f))`

Comment: It just has rewritten the same file (same file size) with a different name but did not perform the function "MyDTM" from the different folder. I think it only took the files from one folder called "ground" and rewritten in the same folder while I wanted to use the files from "ground" folder to create MyDTM which will be used after for MyNorm function. The files from "non_ground" folder will be used to do the MyNorm function along with MyDTM. Actually, I want to use the files from two folders one for one function called MyDTM and another for MyNorm, which will also use the MyDTM.

Comment: Honestly, if there are no efficiency gains from processing these things in the same loop (and it doesn't seem that there are), I would first pre-process the non_ground files in one loop, save them in the ground folder and then in another loop feed all of files through the MyDTM function.